# Jackson mapping missing one key value to map POJO class

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I am facing one issue. Jackson mapping missing one key value to map POJO class.

Using this maven dependancy -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the code -

```
try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        allGroupResponse = mapper.readValue(record, AllGroupResponse.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A POJO Class

```
 public class AllGroupResponse {
        private String status;
        private String data;
        private String message;
        private String tag;
        private List<GroupTable> groupListDTO;
    }
public class GroupTable {

    private String id;
    private String groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private String address;
    private String groupLimit;
    private String groupPairingCode;
    private String zoneId;
    private String siteContactNumber;
    private String programId;
    private String projectId;
    private String createdBy;
    private String updatedBy;
    private String partyProfileId;
    private String groupType;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date updatedDate;
    private Date groupPairingValidity;
    private String groupManagerName;
    private String groupManagerEmail;
    private List<String> userEmailIds;
    private String description;
    private String status;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    private String parentReference;
}
```

This is JSON string -

```
    {
      "data": null,
      "groupListDTO": [
        {
          "groupType": "PARENT",
          "city": null,
          "groupId": "demo site_39329fbf-97ce-4474-bfab-db0f00ffa4b9",
          "description": null,
          "updatedDate": 1562310647155,
          "parentReference": "null",
          "zoneId": "demotest-zone_13f74715-fad9-4517-9cbd-bd47fa7c4df7",
          "id": "0cab0526-ce7c-4cd8-80cd-77e1e7e52b29",
          "state": null,
          "groupLimit": null,
          "address": "Mu",
          "updatedBy": "nishant@gmail.com",
          "groupManagerEmail": null,
          "groupPairingCode": null,
          "groupManagerName": null,
          "groupName": "Demo Site",
          "createdDate": 1557490542612,
          "createdBy": null,
          "groupPairingValidity": null,
          "partyProfileId": null,
          "siteContactNumber": "",
          "projectId": "ab4dafed-7fd9-46c0-ab9a-b28d756c4f11",
          "programId": null,
          "userEmailIds": ["jl@gmail.com"],
          "status": "UPDATED"
        }
      ],
   "tag": "GROUP_LIST_FOUND",
   "message": "Get all the group list for user.",
   "status": "SUCCESS"

    }
```

After mapping to the POJO Class. Printed toString -

```
AllGroupResponse{status='SUCCESS', data='null', message='Get all the group list for user.', tag='GROUP_LIST_FOUND', groupListDTO=[GroupTable{id='0cab0526-ce7c-4cd8-80cd-77e1e7e52b29', groupId='demo site_39329fbf-97ce-4474-bfab-db0f00ffa4b9', groupName='Demo Site', address='Mu', groupLimit='null', groupPairingCode='null', zoneId='demotest-zone_13f74715-fad9-4517-9cbd-bd47fa7c4df7', siteContactNumber='', programId='null', projectId='ab4dafed-7fd9-46c0-ab9a-b28d756c4f11', createdBy='null', updatedBy='nishant@gmail.com', partyProfileId='null', groupType='PARENT', createdDate=Fri May 10 17:45:42 IST 2019, updatedDate=Fri Jul 05 12:40:47 IST 2019, groupPairingValidity=null, groupManagerName='null', groupManagerEmail='null', userEmailIds=[jl@gmail.com], description='null', status='UPDATED', city='null', state='null'}]}
```

Here I found the key `"parentReference": "null"` is missing. I understand the value null is in string format. But it should map as it is considered String.

I don't understand why it is happening. There is no exception occurred. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Can you add the code of your POJO class ? The field is probably missing

Comment: Please check I have updated POJO class. Field is there, Its not missing @Arnaud Claudel

Comment: The POJO doesn't seem to be the right one, you are trying to map a `AllGroupResponse` object, not a `GroupTable` one .

Comment: `private String parentReference` is at the end of the class, did you add it later ? Are you sure that you're running the latest compiled version ?

Comment: I think it is toString() issue. Did you try to stop in debug and view fields of allGroupResponse? Also check toString implementation

Comment: I have updated the proper string and whole POJO now. Please check once again. I haven't added anything later. its still the same issue. @Arnaud

Comment: Thanks !! Yes I forgot to add this updated parameter so that it was not printing when toString() method gets called. @alexey28

Comment: @TejasRatunawar Please close the questionn if issue is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add updated parameter in toString() method -
Thanks @alexey28

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GroupTable{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", groupId='" + groupId + '\'' +
                ", groupName='" + groupName + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", groupLimit='" + groupLimit + '\'' +
                ", groupPairingCode='" + groupPairingCode + '\'' +
                ", zoneId='" + zoneId + '\'' +
                ", siteContactNumber='" + siteContactNumber + '\'' +
                ", programId='" + programId + '\'' +
                ", projectId='" + projectId + '\'' +
                ", createdBy='" + createdBy + '\'' +
                ", updatedBy='" + updatedBy + '\'' +
                ", partyProfileId='" + partyProfileId + '\'' +
                ", groupType='" + groupType + '\'' +
                ", createdDate=" + createdDate +
                ", updatedDate=" + updatedDate +
                ", groupPairingValidity=" + groupPairingValidity +
                ", groupManagerName='" + groupManagerName + '\'' +
                ", groupManagerEmail='" + groupManagerEmail + '\'' +
                ", userEmailIds=" + userEmailIds +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", parentReference='" + parentReference + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```